# I do not understand this syntax error

Tags: python

I am doing the Python tutorial byte of python 120-1 pdf

Here are the instructions:

> Start your choice of editor, enter the following program and save it
>   as helloworld.py
>
> Example 3.2. Using a Source File
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # Filename : helloworld.py
> print 'Hello World'
> ```
>
> (Source file: code/helloworld.py) Run this program by opening a shell
>   (Linux terminal or DOS prompt) and entering the command python
>   helloworld.py. If you are using IDLE, use the menu Edit -> Run Script
>   or the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-F5. The output is as shown below.
>
> Output
>
> ```
> $ python helloworld.py
>
> Hello World
> ```

I entered the program into text wrangler and saved it as helloworld.py

I then opened my terminal and entered python helloworld.py.

I received syntax error: invalid syntax

I then tried helloworld.py and also received syntax error: invalid syntax

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Show us exact content of your file.

Comment: Are you usisg Python 3? In this version `print` is function. So you have to write `print('Hello World')`.

Answer (score 6):

You're using 2.x documentation, but are running 3.x. Either downgrade Python, or find more recent material.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename : helloworld.py
print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Then you're going to need to add more details to the question.